# VS Code Prettier format Apex classes

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex, prettier

I've setup VS Code and I have Prettier working for everything except for Apex classes (*.cls).
I've added the following snippet to my .prettierrc file, but I'm not seeing any changes.

```
{
    "files": "*.cls",
    "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
}
```

I'd like prettier to auto format my .cls files, but I'm not sure what the .prettierrc file needs to look like...

I'm sure it's easy enough to do, but I'm unfamiliar with Prettier and didn't see anything online for .cls files.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an article here that walks you through how to setup apex support for prettier.

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/prettier